# Folding Styled Components Consts in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, styled-components

I have been using Styled Components in NextJS/React and I love it.  Generally, I break my styles out into separate js files, but because I am relatively new to React, props, hooks, and context and such, I often find need to keep my styles in my component files.  My question is how do I, in VSCode, fold the following code:

```
const SomeStyledComponent = styled.div`
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  ...
`;
```

It would go a long way to make my coding life easier.

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `indentation` code folding strategy.

```
// settings.json
{
//  ...other settings
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
}
```

From the [settings doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings):

> Controls the strategy for computing folding ranges. `auto` uses a language specific folding strategy, if available. `indentation` uses the indentation based folding strategy.